# Smoothing of a step function using smoothstep. (Curve fitting)

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, curves, approximation-theory

I was trying to smoothen the step function (zero when $x$ is less than $2/3$ and equal to $1$ when $x$ is greater then $5/6$) as in the picture below.  Trying to fit $f$ in between $2/3$ and $5/6$ using [smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) $f(x)=3x^2- 2x^3$. Also used the stretching/contraction of $x$ axis and translation of $x$ axis but could not actually fit it.

[image]

Comment: You question is unclear to me. What do yo mean by 'Smooth' ? Where does the problem come from?

Comment: Sorry,  actually we have a step function, darkened lines in the figure and since it is not continuous and smooth we try to make it smooth by inserting a function which is smooth at both the ends,  for this it is recommended to use the function $f = 3x^2 -2x^3$,  but I am finding it difficult to fit the function in between 2/3 to 5/6..https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep

Comment: that is because your function looks misaligned... the value at $x=\frac{2}{3}$ is not 0, when it should be... I think you just messed up while solving one of the differential equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function as in your link,
$$ \texttt{SmoothStep}:[0,1]\to \mathbb R, \\ \texttt{SmoothStep}(x) = 3x^2 - 2x^3$$
interpolates between 0 and 1 while having zero derivative at the endpoints $0,1$. You want to $(A)$ squish this to an interval of length $\frac56 - \frac23 = \frac16$ and $(B)$ make the function start at $2/3$ instead of 0. Lets do these one at a time.

- $(A)$ squishing a function horizontally amounts to making the function run through its input faster. For instance $2x$ over $x\in[0,2]$ goes from 0 to 4. If you want it to end up at 4 when $x=0.1$, you're gonna need to use $2(2x/0.1)=40x$ instead. Therefore, to accomplish $(A)$, you want to use
  $$ f_1(x) = \texttt{SmoothStep}(6x)$$
- $(B)$ Moving a function to the right corresponds to moving the inputs to the left. This slight awkwardness is behind the fact that e.g. $x-3$ has root $+3$, not $-3$. So our final result is
  $$ f_2(x) = f_1(x-2/3) = \texttt{SmoothStep}\Big(6(x-2/3)\Big).$$

Plots to verify this is correct:

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  that helps!